# Enabling CPU Core on Linux after Boot

Tags: linux, arm

I saw an older post on how to disable Core for Linux by modifying the uboot variable maxcpu, reference link below. 
[diabling cpu cores on quad core processor on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145645/diabling-cpu-cores-on-quad-core-processor-on-linux)

My question is, is there a way to boot Linux on 1 core, and then later enable another core?

I have a Dual-Core Cortex A9 system, and I want to run Linux boot on one core, and a bare-metal application on another core while linux is booting. Then once Linux has completed booting and the bare-metal application is done with its task, I want the baremetal application to "die" and Linux to take control of the second core.

Now I did do some reading about AMP and how it's possible to separate the two application yet have them communicate by the OCM (on chip memory).

I'm completely new to this field, so any and all suggestions and advice is VERY appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please see this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326579/how-to-ensure-exclusive-cpu-availability-for-a-running-process

Comment: What SoC is it exactly?

Comment: Xilinx Zybo Board